# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "driver" is null

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting error like  inside TEstNGListener onTestFailure sMethod=ValidateUserAbleToDownloadFileOnPartnerConfigurationPage]
2023-03-14 14:45:26 ERROR TestngListener:124 - The complete Exception for the Debugging: [Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "driver" is null]
inside TEstNGListener onTestFailure sMethod=ValidateUserAbleToDownloadFileOnPartnerConfigurationPage]
2023-03-14 14:45:26 ERROR TestngListener:124 - The complete Exception for the Debugging: [Cannot invoke "com.im.apac.wrapper.api.IHTMLWebDriver.logFailureAndTakeScreensot(String)" because "hDriver" is null]
Exception in thread "TestNG-test=Test-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.im.apac.wrapper.api.IHTMLWebDriver.logFailureAndTakeScreensot(String)" because "hDriver" is null
at com.im.apac.utility.listener.TestngListener.onTestFailure(TestngListener.java:130)
at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:67)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1389)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1042)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)``

I found solutions for that -
if your chrome driver version is 111.0.5563.65 then use its latest below version like 110.0.5481.
above thing solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions for that - if your chrome driver version is 111.0.5563.65 then use its latest below version like 110.0.5481. above thing solve my issue